Hitting metal behind drywall near window
I’m trying to install a shelf near a window. When drilling holes for screws, I hit metal about half an inch behind the drywall. What is this? Can I safely keep drilling using my drill bits?
There is no electrical outlet near this area, but I am about two inches away from a window frame.
See pictures: https://imgur.com/a/KavsJpc
Thanks

what sort of window?

While not likely, it's possible you've encountered a protection plate (https://www.lowes.com/pd/Oatey-Steel-Safety-Plate/1001149348).  Using a small drill bit, prob the drywall at various places around the point where metal was found.  Until you know the what and why of that metal, don't pierce it.

That close to the window, I'd have to say it's a metal framing stud. If you want to take a chance, use a smaller drill bit and slowly drill into it. The stud would only be about 1/16" where as anything else would be thicker. If you drill through quickly, it's a stud and you can enlarge the hole.
